# getting authentication failed when switching from demo to production

Tags: c#, docusignapi

I'm working through replacing my existing Rest API code to utilize the [C# SDK](https://github.com/docusign/docuSign-csharp-client). As quite simply it's easier for someone to understand than what my original rushed implementation was. When I run through on demo, it's successfully sending the envelope. When i switch the base url from https://demo.docusign.net/restapi to https://www.docusign.net/restapi and update the password to my production password I begin getting the following error.

```
Failed with ErrorCode: 401, Message: Error calling CreateEnvelope: {
    "errorCode": "USER_AUTHENTICATION_FAILED",
    "message": "One or both of Username and Password are invalid."
}
```

This gets successfully called and returns the account id

```
 AuthenticationApi authApi = new AuthenticationApi();
 LoginInformation loginInfo = authApi.Login();
```

However this returns the authentication error. I verified that the authentication failed message.

```
EnvelopesApi envelopesApi = new EnvelopesApi();
EnvelopeSummary envelopeSummary = envelopesApi.CreateEnvelope(_accountKey, envDef);
```

I verified that envelopesApi.Configuration.DefaultHeader matches what the login has and I'm not sure what other options there are.

Comment: Do you happen to know if your PROD account is on the NA2 environment? If so you will want to use https://na2.docusign.net/... as the base URL

Comment: Thank you. Knew it had to be something simple.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you've already resolved but for the benefit of the community- When moving from DocuSign demo to DocuSign production your production account will not always reside on `www`.  It might also be on `na2`, `na3`, `eu1`, etc.

The only way to know for sure (and also to minimize errors and avoid hard-coding) is to write your integration such that it makes the `get::Login()` API and parse the `baseUrl` that is returned, then use that domain in your subsequent requests.  (Note: If building a user application you need to use the UserInfo() [OAuth2](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/guide/authentication/auth_server.html) endpoint to retrieve the account specific URL.)

Comment: Is there any information around which SDK method we should be using to get the target baseUrl?

Comment: In each Swagger SDK readme there is an authentication section which has a good description of the steps.  For instance, see the Authentication section in the C# SDK here (under the Usage section):  https://github.com/docusign/docusign-csharp-client